# Embedded Twitter feed won't render nicely when loaded via Ajax

Tags: ajax, twitter

If you paste a Tweet URL to your post, Wordpress will nicely render it.

But if I load posts via Ajax, the URL gets replaced by a Blockquote, but not with the nicely rendered one. The class of the Blockquote is `twitter-tweet` and not, as intended `twitter-tweet-rendered` with all that extra stuff.

This is what it looks like loaded via Ajax:

[image]

And this is what it looks like loaded by normal request:

[image]

So is there any Javascript action that I could fire to render that Twitter Feed?

This is how I load it:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: link, // this is generated via the "next_posts" link
            success: function(respond) {

                // get the right content
                var $result = $(respond).find('.content article');

                // append the content
                $('.content').append( $result );

            },
            error: function(html) {
            }
        });
```

Alternate Ajax request:

```
    $.post(
        my_global.ajaxurl,
        {
            action : 'return_tweet_post'
        },
        function( respond ) {
                    // append it
                }
```

And the PHP action for it:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_return_tweet_post', 'return_tweet_post' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_return_tweet_post', 'return_tweet_post' );
function return_tweet_post() {
    $my_query = new WP_Query('p=1165');
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
            $my_query->the_post(); 

            the_content();
        }
    }
    exit;
}
```

Gives the same result.

Comment: Please elaborate how are you retrieving content via Ajax. It might be relevant to how oEmbed handles things.

Comment: So you are ripping post content out of normal web page?.. Why not properly request it via Ajax from backend?

Comment: I've tried a "proper" Ajax request (if you mean using `wp_ajax` by "properly request it"), but it returns the same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, got it.

Need to embed

```
<script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

manually

And then fire `twttr.widgets.load();` after appending the posts.

Thx anyways, Rarst